# Turning JSON into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a json file that has a list of songs that I want to move into specific html ids using a jquery function. Here is 2 of the five songs in my json file (all follow the same format:

```
{
    "songs": [
        {
            "title": "Hotel California",
            "artist": "Eagles",
            "album": "Hotel California",
            "album_cover": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel_California_(Eagles_album)#/media/File:Hotelcalifornia.jpg",
            "release_date": "1976",
            "site": "http://www.allmusic.com/album/hotel_california",
            "generes": "Rock"
        },
        {
            "title": "Back in Black",
            "artist": "ACDC",
            "album": "Back in Black",
            "album_cover": "http://www.billboard.com/files/styles/review_main_image/public/media/acdc-back-in-black-album-cover-650.jpg",
            "release_date": "1980",
            "site": "http://www.allmusic.com/album/back_in_black",
            "generes": "Rock"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my html that I am trying to have my data loaded into:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Json</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a id="site" href="#">
    <img id="coverart" src="noalbum.png" />
  </a>
  <h1 id="title"></h1>
  <h2 id="artist"></h2>
  <h2 id="album"></h2>
  <p id="date"></p>
  <ul id="genres">
  </ul>
</body>
<script src="my.js"></script>  
</html>
```

I am trying to create a function that fills these tags with the appropriate data and repeats the process until all of the songs are molded to the above html format just repeated. Here is my js file so far:

```
$("a").click(function() {
  GetIndexData()
});

function GetIndexData() {
  var param = "&nocache=" + Math.random() * 1000000;
  $.getJSON('my.js', param, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      $('#' + key).html(val);
    })
  });
}
```

Any help would be great thank you!

Comment: One quick thing: if your JSON file is named `lab4`, then in your getJSON call you want it to be `lab4.json`. Also are you getting any console errors?

Comment: It's not clear how you want that JSON to be shown in the HTML. The JSON contains an array of songs, but you only have a place for one song in the HTML. Which song should go into the HTML?

Comment: Why is `genres` a list in the HTML, but a single string in the JSON? Shouldn't it be something like `"genres": ["Rock", "Punk"]`

Comment: If you want to display multiple songs, you shouldn't use IDs, you should use classes. Then you can use `$(".title").eq(i)` to select a specific title to fill in. Will the HTML always have enough copies of these elements to match the JSON array? Maybe you should create the HTML dynamically instead of filling it in.

Comment: To add to what @Barmar said, yes, for this type of thing you should create a single "song" template, which contains elements that you can fill in. Then in your `$.each()` you can create a clone of that element using jQuery's `.clone()`, fill in the pieces of data, and append it to a "songs" container

Comment: You can do it a bit like this, just I used plain js (it's not a recommended way for a production website, but I guess it will do for learning) https://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/p2nx0mt6/7/

Answer (score 0):

So you are pulling in a JSON file that has a list of songs and the details. I came up with this based on the cod snipides that you provided.

You have to grate an HTML template that will be populated with your data. in doing this you will have to use classes instead of ids. I the ran the array of songs through a forEach loop to fill everything in.

I also changed your generes into an array; if it is meant to be so. If it is not I also have a version that renders it as a single value.

```
    function render(data) {
        data.forEach(function(item) {
            var templ = $('<div class="album-wrap"> <a class="site" href="' + item.site + '"><img class="coverart" src="' + item.album_cover + '"/></a><h1 class="title">' + item.title + '</h1><h2 class="artist">' + item.artist + '</h2><h2 class="album">' + item.album + '</h2><p class="date">' + item.release_date + '</p><ul class="genres"></ul></div>'),
                generesLi = templ.find('.genres');

            generesRender(item.generes, generesLi);

            $('body').append(templ);
        });
    }

    function generesRender(arr, elem) {
        arr.forEach(function(item) {
            elem.append('<li>' + item + '</li>');
        });
    }
    render(data);
```

And this is if generes is not an array.

```
 function render(data) {
            data.forEach(function(item) {
                var templ = $('<div class="album-wrap"> <a class="site" href="' + item.site + '"><img class="coverart" src="' + item.album_cover + '"/></a><h1 class="title">' + item.title + '</h1><h2 class="artist">' + item.artist + '</h2><h2 class="album">' + item.album + '</h2><p class="date">' + item.release_date + '</p><p class="genres">' + item.generes + '</p></div>');
                $('body').append(templ);
            });
        }
```

Your getJSON call is also off. I does not take a param (that i know of) and you do not need it. So it should be like this.

```
$.getJSON('my.js', function(data) {
    render(data);
});
```

I used JSON that was on the page though. I looked like this.

```
var data = [{
            "title": "Hotel California",
            "artist": "Eagles",
            "album": "Hotel California",
            "album_cover": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel_California_(Eagles_album)#/media/File:Hotelcalifornia.jpg",
            "release_date": "1976",
            "site": "http://www.allmusic.com/album/hotel_california",
            "generes": ["Rock", "Country", "Electric"]
        }, {
            "title": "Back in Black",
            "artist": "ACDC",
            "album": "Back in Black",
            "album_cover": "http://www.billboard.com/files/styles/review_main_image/public/media/acdc-back-in-black-album-cover-650.jpg",
            "release_date": "1980",
            "site": "http://www.allmusic.com/album/back_in_black",
            "generes": ["Rock", "Jazz"]
        }];
```

So if your data looks like this the solution should work. If it does not then console log it and post what you get and I'll make adjustments.